# Can one machine be the part of two Microsoft failover clusters?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cluster, windows-cluster

Can one machine be the part(the node) of two Microsoft failover clusters or not?

Comment: In what way does that make sense? If the machine fails, which way would you want the services to go? Say it is, `A B C` with B as the shared host and `B` fails, the services fail to one of the others, e.g. `A` ... and then `A` fails, what happens? The service clusters were A-B and B-C - either it was on B, B-C were connected and C is running therefore the service should be running, or should it be failed because A only had partner B and A-B are down. It can't be both, and it can't get from A-C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible (and not supported of course). A Windows machine node cluster can be only part of one failover cluster.

If you want to do that for a OS migration purpose, Windows Server 2016 will allow a mix of Windows Server 2012 R2 ans 2016 nodes to make easier the cluster migration.

Regards